# SQL LIKE Find Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following search sql query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [EmployeeSearch]
@PayrollNumber  varchar(50) = null,
@isInternal     bit = null,
@Firstname      varchar(50) = null,
@Surname        varchar(50) = null
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select EmployeeSearchView.*
From   EmployeeSearchView
Where
EmployeeSearchView.isInternal = @isInternal
AND 
(EmployeeSearchView.PayrollNumber LIKE '%' + @PayrollNumber + '%'
OR  EmployeeSearchView.Firstname LIKE '%' + @Firstname + '%'
OR  EmployeeSearchView.Surname LIKE '%' + @Surname + '%'
```

Only problem is when the FirstName or Surname is send through as an empty string '' it returns the wrong values...if i pass null values it works..how can I fix this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add another and clause to check for empty strings?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [EmployeeSearch]
@PayrollNumber  varchar(50) = null,
@isInternal             bit = null,
@Firstname              varchar(50) = null,
@Surname                varchar(50) = null
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select EmployeeSearchView.*
From   EmployeeSearchView
Where
EmployeeSearchView.isInternal = @isInternal
AND 
(EmployeeSearchView.PayrollNumber LIKE '%' + @PayrollNumber + ' %'
OR  (@Firstname <> '' AND EmployeeSearchView.Firstname LIKE '%' + @Firstname + ' %')
OR  (@Surname   <> '' AND EmployeeSearchView.Surname LIKE '%' + @Surname + ' %')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [EmployeeSearch]
@PayrollNumber  varchar(50) = null,
@isInternal             bit = null,
@Firstname              varchar(50) = null,
@Surname                varchar(50) = null
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (IsNull(@FirstName, '') = '') 
    SET @FirstName = '%'
ELSE
    SET @FirstName = '%' + @FirstName + '%';
END

IF (IsNull(@Surname, '') = '') 
    SET @Surname = '%'
ELSE
    SET @Surname = '%' + @Surname + '%';
END

Select EmployeeSearchView.*
From   EmployeeSearchView
Where
EmployeeSearchView.isInternal = @isInternal
AND 
(EmployeeSearchView.PayrollNumber LIKE '%' + @PayrollNumber + '%'
AND  EmployeeSearchView.Firstname LIKE @Firstname
AND EmployeeSearchView.Surname LIKE @Surname
```